# Intellisense has refreshed but the update statement is not working for SSMS 2017

Tags: sql, sql-server

I was working around on using SQL for the SSMS 2017, but ran into a small problem. The UPDATE statement is not working for some reason. I did some digging and saw that I need to refresh my IntelliSense (which I did), but it is still not able to find the object. So, I went to Tools>Options>Text Editor>IntelliSense and changed the limit, and it still did not work. I checked if I am in the same database, and I was. Then, I even refreshed, reconnected into the database, still nothing.

This is how I inserted into the table.

```
INSERT INTO Customer 
(FirstName,LastName,[Age], City) VALUES ('Joey', 'Tribbiani', 38,'New York');
INSERT INTO Customer 
(FirstName,LastName,[Age], City) VALUES ('Chandler', 'Bing', 38,'New York');
INSERT INTO Customer 
(FirstName,LastName,[Age], City) VALUES ('Ross', 'Geller', 36,'New York');
INSERT INTO Customer 
(FirstName,LastName,[Age], City) VALUES ('Rachel', 'Green', 32,'New York');
INSERT INTO Customer 
(FirstName,LastName,[Age], City) VALUES ('Monica', 'Geller', 32,'New York');
INSERT INTO Customer 
(FirstName,LastName,[Age], City) VALUES ('Phoebe', 'Buffay', 35,'New York');
```

And I wanted to update the column "City", so I wrote this:

```
UPDATE City
SET City = 'Vegas';
```

So, the console is saying that City object is not found.

Comment: UPDATE Customer table, not City.

Comment: That was a serious oversight, thank you for pointing it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think of it this way, you want to update the `City` column but you need to specify where to find the `City` column, as of now the interpreter does not know where this column is. So you specify the table name to where the column exists after the `UPDATE` command.

```
UPDATE Customer
SET City = 'Vegas';
```

As mentioned on this [tutorial](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/sql-update-query.htm) it has the syntax of a simple `UPDATE` command.

```
UPDATE table_name
SET column1 = value1, column2 = value2...., columnN = valueN
WHERE [condition];
```

Comment: That was a serious oversight, thank you for pointing it out